# Execute stored procedure from batch file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, batch-file

How would you execute a stored procedure in SQL Server (using windows authentication) from a batch file?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are using Sql Server 2005+, you can use [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180944.aspx) utility.

Example:

sqlcmd -Q "exec storedProcName" -S YourServer -d YourDatabase -o C:\yourOutput.txt

Comment: and you put this in a .bat file and run using cmd?

Comment: Yes, you can execute from a .bat file.

Answer (score 5):

With SQL Server 2005 and above you can use sqlcmd.exe.
More info about how to use it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170572.aspx

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=109770

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sqlcmd.exe`  See: [MSDN usages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)