# Import data from Excel to SQL Server automatically for every 15 min of time using MS Task Scheduler

Tags: sql-server

How can I import data from Excel to SQL Server using MS Task Scheduler

Comment: Google helps occasionally:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-data-from-excel-to-sql?view=sql-server-2017#linked-servers

or:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/best-way-to-push-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-no-of-rows-keep/td-p/107182

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a stored procedure with Bulk Insert in SQL Server. In Bulk
   import query itself you can specify the file location and Table
   structure. [Refer this link for Bulk insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13124680/how-to-bulk-insert-from-xlsx-file-extension)
2. Create a batch file
   and call the stored procedure using [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-the-utility?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) command. [Refer this
   link for Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980353/execute-stored-procedure-from-batch-file)
3. Task Schedule the batch file using windows task scheduler. [Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437701/run-a-batch-file-with-windows-task-scheduler)